# React-table. the column header starts with the second line, not the first

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I would like the header of the first cell to start from the first row, and not from the second. So that the cell is one whole, and not divided into two.[image]

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-pagination-and-sort-forked-slnpt4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Should "Фамилия" be preserved column ?

Comment: Absolutely right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to leave empty space in `Header` property. So the code would look like this:

```
const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "First Name",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "",
            accessor: "firstName"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        Header: "Фамилия",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "lastName",
            accessor: "lastName"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    []
  );
```

It looks like this:

[image]

[Please, see the complete example at codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-pagination-and-sort-forked-zj7szj?file=/src/App.js)

UPDATE:

It is possible to remove border line in cells through CSS:

```
table thead tr:first-child th:first-child {  
  border-bottom: 0px solid #777;
}

table thead tr:nth-child(even) th:first-child {  
  border-top: 0px;
}
```

[Please, see an updated example at sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-pagination-and-sort-forked-zj7szj?file=/src/index.css:473-625)

Comment: That's what was need! And to make a single cell, without dividing in the middle, as I understand it, will not work?

Comment: @Schekhovtsov please, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:

```
<thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup, index) =>
            index > 0 ? (
              <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                  // Add the sorting props to control sorting. For this example
                  // we can add them into the header props
                  <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
                    {column.render("Header")}
                    {/* Add a sort direction indicator */}
                  </th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ) : null
          )}
        </thead>
```

[here is the running code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8ne2.png)